# How to get LinkedIn followers count?

Tags: javascript, api, linkedin-api

I tried to get the LinkedIn followers count using JavaScript:

```
<div id="statusDiv">Result</div><script type="text/javascript"  src="http://platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
                api_key: XXXXX
onLoad: onLinkedInLoad
authorize: true
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function onLinkedInLoad() {
  IN.API.Raw("/companies/<<company_id>>:(num-followers)")
.result( function(result) { document.getElementById("statusDiv").innerHTML =  result.numFollowers; } )
.error( function(error) {  document.getElementById("statusDiv").innerHTML = error } );
 }
 </script>
```

but this does not work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks fine.  Check your javascript console for errors.  I suspect you have not configured your "Javascript API Domains" value properly in your LinkedIn application's settings.

Here's a slightly cleaner version of the same code that I just saw working successfully with a properly configured LinkedIn application:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://platform.linkedin.com/in.js" type="text/javascript">
      api_key: xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
      onLoad: onLinkedInLoad
      authorize: true
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function onLinkedInLoad() {
            IN.API.Raw("/companies/1337:(num-followers)").result(onSuccess).error(onError);
        }

        function onSuccess(data) {
            document.getElementById("statusDiv").innerHTML =  data.numFollowers;
        }

        function onError(error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="statusDiv">Result</div>
  </body>
</html>
```